# Unhandled Exception: Stack Overflow on customDropDown ValueChanged

Tags: flutter, dart

I created a custom drop down.

```
class CustomDropDown extends StatefulWidget{
   String selectValue,hintText;
   List<String> valueList;
   final double width;
   final double height;
   final Color textColor;
   final FontWeight fontWeight;
   final ValueChanged<String> onChanged;

   CustomDropDown({Key key,this.fontWeight,this.height = 40.0,this.hintText,this.onChanged, this.textColor, this.selectValue, this.valueList,this.width}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _CustomDropDownState createState() => _CustomDropDownState();
}

class _CustomDropDownState extends State<CustomDropDown> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Container(
      height: widget.height,
      width: widget.width,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Palette.white,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5)),
        border: Border.all(width: 1, color: Palette.darkSilver),
      ),
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
        child: DropdownButton<String>(
          isExpanded: true,
          value: widget.selectValue,
          onChanged:widget.onChanged,
          items: widget.valueList.map((String value) {
            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
              value: value,
              child: CustomText(
                  text: value,
                  textColor: widget.textColor,
                  fontWeight: widget.fontWeight),
            );
          }).toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**called from everywhere, this is inside build method**

```
CustomDropDown(
                      selectValue: selectGender,
                      valueList: genderList,
                      width: width,
                      textColor: Palette.darkOrange,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      onChanged:onChangedGender
                    ),
```

outside build method

```
  ValueChanged<String> onChangedGender(String value){
    setState(() {
       selectGender = value;
    });
    return onChangedGender(value);
  }
```

Error in the console, why is this happening?

```
Unhandled Exception: Stack Overflow
E/flutter (14614): #0      Element.markNeedsBuild.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3872:12)
E/flutter (14614): #1      Element.markNeedsBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3911:6)
E/flutter (14614): #2      State.setState (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1168:14)
E/flutter (14614): #3      _AccountInfoPageState.onChanged (package:accountInfo/accountInfoPage.dart:187:8)
E/flutter (14614): #4      _AccountInfoPageState.onChanged (package:accountInfo/accountInfoPage.dart:190:20)
E/flutter (14614): #5      _AccountInfoPageState.onChanged (package:accountInfo/accountInfoPage.dart:190:20)
E/flutter (14614): #6      _AccountInfoPageState.onChanged (package:accountInfo/accountInfoPage.dart:190:20)
E/flutter (14614): #7      _AccountInfoPageState.onChanged (package:accountInfo/accountInfoPage.dart:190:20)
E/flutter (14614): #8      _AccountInfoPageState.onChanged (package:accountInfo/accountInfoPage.dart:190:20)
E/flutter (14614): #9      _AccountInfoPageState.onChanged (package:accountInfo/accountInfoPage.dart:190:20)
E/flutter (14614): #10     _AccountInfoPageState.onChanged (package:accountInfo/accountInfoPage.dart:190:20)
E/flutter (14614): #11     _AccountInfoPageState.onChanged (package:accountInfo/accountInfoPage.dart:190:20)
E/flutter (14614): #12     _AccountInfoPageState.onChanged (package:accountInfo/accountInfoPage.dart:190:20)
E/flutter (14614): #13     _AccountInfoPageState.onChanged (package:accountInfo/accountInfoPage.dart:190:20)
E/flutter (14614): #14     _AccountInfoPageState.onChanged (package:accountInfo/accountInfoPage.dart:190:20)
E/flutter (14614): #15     _AccountInfoPageState.onChanged (package:accountInfo/accountInfoPage.dart:190:20)
E/flutter (14614): #16     _AccountInfoPageState.onChanged (package:accountInfo/accountInfoPage.dart:190:20)
E/flutter (14614): #17     _AccountInfoPageState.onChanged (package:accountInfo/accountInfoPage.dart:190:20)
E/flutter (14614): #18     _AccountInfoPageState.onChanged (package:accountInfo/accountInfoPage.dart:190:20)
E/flutter (14614): #19     _AccountInfoPageState.onChanged (package:accountInfo/accountInfoPage.dart:190:20)
E/flutter (14614): #20     _AccountInfoPageState.onChanged (package:accountInfo/accountInfoPage.dart:190:20)
E/flutter (14614): #21     _AccountInfoPageState.onChanged (package:accountInfo/accountInfoPage.dart:190:20)
E/flutter (14614): #22     _AccountInfoPageState.onChanged (package:accountInfo/accountInfoPage.dart:190:20)
E/flutter (14614): #23     _AccountInfoPageState.onChanged (package:accountInfo/accountInfoPage.dart:190:20)
E/flutter (14614): #24     _AccountInfoPageState.onChanged (package:accountInfo/accountInfoPage.dart:190:20)
E/flutter (14614): #25     _AccountInfoPageState.onChanged (package:accountInfo/accountInfoPage.dart:190:20)
E/flutter (14614): #26     _AccountInfoPageState.onChanged (package:accountInfo/accountInfoPage.dart:190:20)
E/flutter (14614): #27     _AccountInfoPageState.onChanged (package:accountInfo/accountInfoPage.dart:190:20)
E/flutter (14614): #28     _AccountInfoPageState.onChanged (package:accountInfo/accountInfoPage.dart:190:20)
E/flutter (14614): #29     _AccountInfoPageState.onChanged (package:accountInfo/accountInfoPage.dart:190:20)
E/flutter (14614): #30     _AccountInfoPageState.onChanged (package:accountInfo/accountInfoPage.dart:190:20)
E/flutter (14614): #31     _AccountInfoPageState.onChanged (package:accountInfo/accountInfoPage.dart:190:20)
E/flutter (14614): #32     _AccountInfoPageState.onChanged (package:accountInfo/accountInfoPage.dart:190:20)
E/flutter (14614): #33     _AccountInfoPageState.onChanged (package:accountInfo/accountInfoPage.dart:190:20)
E/flutter (14614): #34     _AccountInfoPageState.onChanged (package:accountInfo/accountInfoPage.dart:190:20)
E/flutter (14614): #35     _AccountInfoPageState.onCha
```

Comment: you are calling `return onChangedGender(value)` inside `onChangedGender()` method

Comment: @pskink it's mean no need to `return` right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a recursive call inside `onChangeGender()`, since it doesn't have any means to stop the recursive calls, it will keep calling and filling the stack until the stack overflows.

`ValueChanged<T>` is just a definition for a function that accepts a value and returns nothing:

```dart
typedef ValueChanged<T> = void Function(T value);
```

So you just need to passa a function that's compatible, like:

```dart
void onChangeGender(String value) {
... 
}
```

No need for a return value, that return value will always be ignored by the `ValueChanged<T>` definition.

You could make it even simpler, passing:

```dart
onChanged: (value) => setState(() => selectGender = value),
```

Fortunately asking about Stack Overflows on Stackoverflow isn't recursive and should be safe :)

Comment: Yes. For what I can see so far, you don't need to return anything.

Comment: If this solves your question, don't forget to vote up and accept.

Comment: Thanks, Sorry for late, I added   `// ignore: missing_return`

Comment: Why do you need that function to return anything? Anyway, you could return `null` or an empty `String` instead.

Comment: I added return because of `ValueChanged<String>` . so, I will return empty `String`

Comment: And why do you need to return a `ValueChanged<String>`? Why not just pass a function that doesn't have any return value?

Comment: I don't think you understood what `ValueChanged` is, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are making recursive call without any stop condition. 
I think you can achieve what you want if you
Change your Function as:

```
_onChangedGender(String value){
     setState(() {
       selectGender = value;
    });
}
```